# SQL statement with count

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I'm doing a homework and I am having problems with the SQL statement for one of the views.
Basically I got restaurants that can make posts and users that can Like the Post (much like Facebook liking process).

The idea is to make a SQL Query that shows me to all posts made by a restaurant with RIF = '1123J' (for example) and the amount of likes that each post have.

These are the Tables Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE 'posts'(
    'ID' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    'restaurant_rif' varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    'content' text NOT NULL,
    'creation_date' datetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ('ID'),
    UNIQUE KEY 'ID' ('ID')
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;

CREATE TABLE 'likes' (
  'post_id' int(11) NOT NULL,
  'restaurant_rif' varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  'user_mail' varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  'liked_date' datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I should get an answer more or less like this:

```
+----------+------------+------------------+
| Post ID  | Contenido  |  Amount of Likes |
+----------+------------+------------------+
|     1    | Test 1     |       12         |
+----------+------------+------------------+
|     2    | Test 2     |       50         |
+----------+------------+------------------+
|     1    | Test 3     |       120        |
+----------+------------+------------------+
```

Comment: If this is homework, then you have no doubt attempted something.  Please edit your question showing your attempt.

Comment: yes as suggested by @GordonLinoff you should show us what you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *, (select count(*) from likes l where l.post_id = p.id) as num_likes
from posts p
where restaurant_rif = '<rif>'
```

Comment: This Works just **perfect**! I was doing the count outside of the parenthesis and selecting *, but i had "syntaxs" errors. I didnt know you could do it like this (and i Didnt want to use a Join). thx!

Comment: So you know the technical term, It's called a correlated scalar subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You could join the two tables and group by the fields of the `posts` table. Note that since the post id is unique anyway group by additional fields won't break it down any more, but this is required as all fields in the `select` list should either be aggregate expressions or items of the `group by` list:

```
SELECT   p.id, p.content, COUNT(*)
FROM     posts p
JOIN     likes l ON p.id = l.post_id
WHERE    p.restaurant_rif = '1123J'
GROUP BY p.id, p.content
```

Comment: Can you group by a text column in MySQL?

Comment: Thx for the edit @Mureinik. I didnt know how to do it in blocks like that.